# When does the "Edit too Minor" option appear?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reviewing

I got a heap of review notices for proposed edits, merely to find that a majority were simply adding "in [this game]" to the end of the title.

I chose to reject them for being too minor, but the option wasn't there? When does this option appear?

Comment: The rash of suggested edits just adding the game name to the title are most definitely invalid edits.

Comment: @frank who's been making these suggestions?

Comment: @badp There was a series of edits suggested yesterday by the user [naomik](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/59241/naomik). Like more than 20. Both Frank and I reached our limit of 20 edits reviewed, just from this user alone.

Comment: Too minor is an incorrect rejection reason here anyway.  The problem isn't that it's missing changes that should be made -- it's actively incorrect.  It's wrong to add the game name to the question in most circumstances.  We have tags for that.

Answer (score 4):

The "too minor" rejection reason has been removed. The current advice is to either reject as incorrect (if applicable), or improve the edit if there's more to be improved. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/134175) for details.